# percent of the photo at different focal lengths

Tags: python, matlab, math, photo

So I am trying to solve this given problem, it is based on a picture of a tower that is 221 feet tall taken from 7 miles away (36960 feet) with a focal length of 200mm. At this distance, the tower takes up 1/10th (10%) of the height of the photo. I need to write a Matlab program that plots what percent of the photo the tower will take up given that the range for the focal length is between 200mm to 2000mm. I am given the equation that solves for the angle of the view, alpha = d/2f where d is the camera sensor used and f is the focal length. I need to make one graph that plots one line for when  d = 24mm and another for when d = 36mm. I have what the graph should look like but I can't seem to get either the equation to work correctly or my values are not in the right places.[image: The y axis is for the percent, x axis is for f ranging from 200 to 2000mm. The blue line represents the 36mm, and the red line represents the 24mm sensor]

```
clear;
close all;
clc;
f = 200:2000; %set focal length
d = 24; %set sensor size
angle = atan(d./(2*f)); %given equation
percent = (angle*36960); %multiply the range and angle 
plot(f,percent)
grid on
xlabel('Focal Length');
xlim([1,2000]); %how far the range is
ylabel('Percent') %label the axes
ylim([0,100])
```

This is what I was trying to use so I believe it is something to do with my equations
I believe there is someway that I need to compare the fact that the tower took up 1/10 of the photo at 200mm but I am not sure how to get that into code and how to plot both at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You have the classic percent problem.
Percent is the ratio of two values. Here you should calculate ration of view and actual height.
To plot two plots in one figure

```
plot(x,y1,x,y2)
```

To fix your code:

```
clear;
close;
clc;
distance = 36960;
originalHeight = 221;

f = 200:2000;
d = 24;
angle = atan(d./(2*f));
viewHeight = (angle*distance);
ratio = viewHeight./originalHeight;
percent24 = 100./ratio;

d = 36;
angle = atan(d./(2*f));
viewHeight = (angle*distance);
ratio = viewHeight./originalHeight;
percent36 = 100./ratio;

plot(f,percent36,f,percent24)
grid on
xlabel('Focal Length');
xlim([200,2000]); %how far the range is
ylabel('Percent') %label the axes
ylim([0,100])
```

Output:

[Matlab Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erf7d.jpg)

One thing bother me most is the mismatch between units. Some of them are in mm and others are in feet. I would convert them all in one.

Comment: Thank you I ended up figuring it out later after I posted the question, it was creating the ratio that was messing me up but I figure I’ll leave the question in case others ever have a problem similar

Comment: Great. Good luck.